# When I click on a link, how can I change the status of another component?

Tags: reactjs

When I click on a button, it redirects me to another component (#2) where there are two states and according to which state it shows one content or another. The default state of the component(#2) is true and what I need to know how to do is that clicking on the button of the component(#1) changes the state to false.

This is for a ReactJs app, im using function components, hooks, no class components

```
Thats the button code:
<Link to="/register">
<button className="btn btn-success btnVerde">
</button>
</Link>

Thats the component#2:
const [state, setState] = React.useState(true);
{state && <div1......../>}
{!state && <div2......./>}
```

I expect to click on the button in component#1, it redirecto to component#2 how default state is true, and change it to false

Answer (score 0):

you could handle the state in the component1, and in your onClick call setState and update the value with the oposite, eg:

```
<button onClick={() => setState({state: !state})}>Click</button>
```

and receive the value as a prop in component2, eg:

```
const Component2 = ({showCustom}) => {
  if(showCustom) {
    return <span> Custom </span>;
  }
  return <span>No Custom</span>;
};
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the idea, it helps me to found the solution, isnt exactly like you but was the same way. Im working whith redux and typescript, so i had to create, type, action, interface and reducer to can save the state in redux and later will use on the second component. So in compnent#1 i did: const change = () => props.changingState(false); and in component#2    useEffect(() => {
    if(props.booleanState){
      showCompanyRegister()
    }
    else {
      showTalentRegister()
    }
  }, []);

Answer (score 0):

Thx to @rcoro that is how I solve the problem component#1:

```
const change = () => props.changingState(false);
<Link to="/register"><button onClick={change}className="btnPink">
         {t("talents_btnReserve")}
        </button>
        </Link>
```

component#2:

```
const showTalentRegister = () => setState(true);
const showCompanyRegister = () => setState(false);

useEffect(() => {
if(props.booleanState){
  showCompanyRegister()
}
else {
  showTalentRegister()
}
```

}, []);